# Поясните синтаксис

Tags: c

Подскажите, как интерпретировать следующее объявление функции

```
void foor (int arr[*]);
```

в коде:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foor (int arr[*]);

int main (void)
{
    int arr [10];
    foor (arr); 
    return 0;
}


void foor (int arr [10])
{
    for (int i = 10; i < 10; ++i)
        arr [i] = 0;
}
```

Данный код компилируется без ошибок.
как можно  интерпретировать параметр `int arr[*]` ?
зачем нужна звездочка в квадратных скобках?

Comment: компилятор gcc  
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zjjsz35K8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Связанные вопросы

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225358/prototype-for-variable-length-arrays
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325958/what-does-asterisk-inside-square-bracket-of-array-declaration-mean-in-c
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371645/why-use-an-asterisk-instead-of-an-integer-for-a-vla-array-parameter-of-a-f

Краткий пересказ. Представьте себе такой прототип функции

```
int sum(int n, int a[n]);
```

Но когда обявляются прототипы (в хедерах), то имена параметров часто упускаются. Но тут есть завязка на это имя. И как раз в этом случае и испольуется такой синтаксис

```
int sum(int, int a[*]);
```